# Python 2 and 3 compatible method to convert bytes to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have a byte string similar to the following.

```
foo = b"\x00\xff"
```

I want to convert `foo` each hex value into an integer. I can use the following in Python 3.

```
In [0]: foo[0]
Out[0]: 0  
In [1]: foo[1]
Out[1]: 255
```

Python 2 requires an `ord()` call.

```
In [0]: ord(foo[0])
Out[0]: 0  
In [1]: ord(foo[1])
Out[1]: 255
```

Is there a nice way to write this in code that has to work across both Python 2 and 3? The `six` package has a `six.byte2int()` function but that doesn't work because it only looks at the first byte and `six.byte2int(foo[0]` fails on Python 3 because `foo[0]` is an integer in Python 3.

Is there a better option than a `if six.PY2` branch?

Comment: Have you looked at the `struct` module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have three options:

- Use a [`bytearray()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray):

  ```
  ba = bytearray(foo)
  ba[0]
  ```
- Use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to unpack your bytes into integers:

  ```
  import struct
  struct.unpack('{}B'.format(len(foo)), foo)
  ```
- Use the [`array` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) to unpack your bytes into integers, in a sequence:

  ```
  import array
  array.array('B', foo)
  ```

Demo (Python 2.7):

```
>>> import struct, array
>>> foo = b"\x00\xff"
>>> list(bytearray(foo))
[0, 255]
>>> struct.unpack('{}B'.format(len(foo)), foo)
(0, 255)
>>> array.array('B', foo)
array('B', [0, 255])
```

Demo (Python 3.4):

```
>>> import struct, array
>>> foo = b"\x00\xff"
>>> list(bytearray(foo))
[0, 255]
>>> struct.unpack('{}B'.format(len(foo)), foo)
(0, 255)
>>> array.array('B', foo)
array('B', [0, 255])
```

Comment: Is there any things I have to note when deciding between the two?

Comment: @TerryChia: A `bytearray` is mutable but doesn't require an import, and is directly indexable. `struct` and `array` are there more for completion sake. `bytearray` and `array.array` are easier to turn back in to bytes again.

Comment: Neat, thanks for the answer (again). Python really has too many useful built-in modules and functions to keep track of. :)

Comment: How can I go from the integers to the original byte string?

Comment: @vonec: Python 2 and 3 compatible again? If `foo` is a sequence of integers, then `bytes(bytearray(foo))`, or `struct.pack('{}B'.format(len(foo)), *foo)` or `array.array('B', foo).tostring()` would all work.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the `struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html). `values = struct.unpack('BB', foo)` should do.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and the answers don't cover six.indexbytes.

```
>>> import six
>>> a = b"test"
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
...     print(six.indexbytes(a, i))
... 
116
101
115
116
```